# Comparing integers of arbitrary types

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the fully typesafe and most flexible (in terms of `constexpr`) way to compare a two integers of two generally unexpected (different) types?

Comment: Seems a better fit for CodeReview to me

Comment: ^ Yes--if you created unit tests for this and they produced unexpected behavior then this would be the right place.

Comment: Check out [`std::common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type).  That'll give you a type you can cast both sides to before the comparison.

Comment: @AndyProwl Not too complex to reveiw here as this code as example of a possible solution. I think, that exist more generic solution of Alexandrescu, Stroustrup or somebody else. I was expecting a more constructive discussion.

Comment: Complex or not code reviews belong on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - within the limits of the FAQ of course.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Well, I changed the question. Is that better?! I think, that all the removed code can be still viewed in editions history.

Comment: I think your problem is discussed in excessive detail [in this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-7-of-n).

Comment: @cHao: Nope. `std::common_type<int, unsigned int>::type` is `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Dukales Making a question arguably worse to make it fit into the scope of the site seems kind of shady to me.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Have you ever noticed that it is solely about integers? `static_assert(std::is_integral< T >::value && !std::is_same< T, bool >::value, "")` would not be superfluous.

Comment: @Dukales Yes and I was editing it right after I hit enter ;)

Comment: @millimoose And what should I do?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious example of a scenario: "all possible ordered pairs of int types"

Comment: @Dukales I believe "ask on code review" was the common suggestion. Although seeing how the question isn't closed as off-topic, it's a moot point.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's an idea: We need to use "the usual arithmetic conversions":

- If both types are unsigned, just compare.
- If both types are signed, just compare.
- If the signedness differs and the signed value is negative, we're done.
- The actual work applies where both values are non-negative and have different signedness. When the unsigned value is larger than the maximal signed value of the signed type, we're done. Otherwise, the unsigned value can be converted to the signed type without changing value, and compared.

Here's an attempt:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>

template <bool SameSignedness> struct IntComparerImpl;

template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr bool IntCompare(T x, U y)
{
    return IntComparerImpl<std::is_signed<T>::value ==
                           std::is_signed<U>::value>::compare(x, y);
}

// same signedness case:
template <> struct IntComparerImpl<true>
{
    template<typename T, typename U>
    static constexpr bool compare(T t, U u)
    {
        return t < u;
    } 
};

// different signedness case:
template <> struct IntComparerImpl<false>
{
    // I1 is signed, I2 is unsigned
    template <typename I1, typename I2>
    static constexpr typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<I1>::value, bool>::type
    compare(I1 x, I2 y)
    {
        return x < 0
            || y > std::numeric_limits<I1>::max()
            || x < static_cast<I1>(y);
    }

    // I1 is unsigned, I2 is signed
    template <typename I1, typename I2>
    static typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<I2>::value, bool>::type
    compare(I1 x, I2 y)
    {
        return !(y < 0)
            && !(x > std::numeric_limits<I2>::max())
            && static_cast<I2>(x) < y;
    }
};
```

Comment: "When the unsigned value is larger than the maximal signed value of the signed type" it seems, that here is some kind of a logic recursion.

Comment: note about comparison of "maximal signed value of the signed type" and unsigned value

Comment: @Dukales: How so? Suppose you're comparing unsigned int 200 and signed char 50. Since 200 is larger than the maximum signed char, which is 127, we're done.

Comment: I added the `true` case, but still needs to be `constexpr`ed.

Comment: @Yakk: Thanks (I was about to do that). I think it's OK now.

Comment: @KerrekSB Unless I missed a change, `constexpr` requires a single line expression without recursion in C++11?  Which means a lot of `?:??::?:` nonsense.

Comment: @Yakk: Oh, yeah, probably... well, consider it a C++14 answer.

Comment: It would probably be a few lines shorter with tag-dispatched overloads rather than template specialization. Meh.

Comment: I think, that `x > std::numeric_limits<I2>::max()` subexpression do not pass inspection `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wsign-conversion -Wconversion`, because there is compared a two integers of different types.

Comment: @Dukales: That may be, but I think it's correct nonetheless, because of the arithmetic conversion rules.

Comment: Maybe `static_cast` should be used here?

Comment: The last case seems to be broken. `IntCompare(1u, 1)` returns true.

Answer (score 3):

[My own solution](http://pastebin.com/ECvzMHzW) is this (based on [N3485.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) §5):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <limits>
#include <utility>

#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>

template< typename L, typename R >
inline constexpr
typename std::enable_if< (std::is_signed< L >::value && !std::is_signed< R >::value), bool >::type
less(L const & lhs, R const & rhs)
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral< L >::value,
                  "lhs value must be of integral type");
    static_assert(std::is_integral< R >::value,
                  "rhs value must be of integral type");
    using T = typename std::common_type< L, R >::type;
    return (lhs < static_cast< L >(0)) || (static_cast< T const & >(lhs) < static_cast< T const & >(rhs));
}

template< typename L, typename R >
inline constexpr
typename std::enable_if< (!std::is_signed< L >::value && std::is_signed< R >::value), bool >::type
less(L const & lhs, R const & rhs)
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral< L >::value,
                  "lhs value must be of integral type");
    static_assert(std::is_integral< R >::value,
                  "rhs value must be of integral type");
    using T = typename std::common_type< L, R >::type;
    return !(rhs < static_cast< R >(0)) && (static_cast< T const & >(lhs) < static_cast< T const & >(rhs));
}

template< typename L, typename R >
inline constexpr
typename std::enable_if< (std::is_signed< L >::value == std::is_signed< R >::value), bool >::type
less(L const & lhs, R const & rhs)
{
    static_assert(std::is_integral< L >::value,
                  "lhs value must be of integral type");
    static_assert(std::is_integral< R >::value,
                  "rhs value must be of integral type");
    return lhs < rhs;
}

namespace
{

static_assert(less(1, 2), "0");
static_assert(less(-1, std::numeric_limits< std::uintmax_t >::max()), "1");
static_assert(less< std::int8_t, std::uintmax_t >(-1, std::numeric_limits< std::uintmax_t >::max()), "2");
static_assert(less< std::intmax_t, std::uint8_t >(-1, std::numeric_limits< std::uint8_t >::max()), "3");
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wsign-compare"
static_assert(!(-1 < std::numeric_limits< unsigned long >::max()), "4");
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
static_assert(less(-1, std::numeric_limits< unsigned long >::max()), "5");

}

int main()
{
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```